# Replace DAQ Assistant for a voltage input with reading a WAV sound file

Tags: labview, nidaqmx, daq-mx

I am trying to convert my WAV sound file into data without using DAQ Assistant. For starters I have this code I have to modify and find code compatible with what I want to do,
can anyone help ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlH0i.png]

Answer (score 1):

You may use just a single [Sound File Read Simple VI](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/lvpict/sfilereadsimple.html) to read your sound file data.
If you need more detailed control of the process, take a look at the whole [Sound palette](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/lvpict/soundvisnew.html)